# When table has enough rows to be indexed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

Adding index (on the relevant column) improves the performance of a query.
However if the table holds only very small amount of rows (less than 100).
I guess adding an index is an overkill (Or am I wrong?) 
Is there a thumb rule, from which amount of rows, you want to start indexing, to improve performance of select queries?

Comment: Most tables may start with a small number of rows but will grow quite fast. If that's the case, create your indexes according to the queries that will hit the db.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from the mysql site

> Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables
>   where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query
>   needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than
>   working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even
>   if not all the rows are needed for the query.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

If you had less elementss the answer would be more difficult,but so yes for 100 you should make an index especially if join wnat to join tables and for tables that grow definitely and index.

Interesting gets also when you should combine indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the optimal indexes.  Let the Optimizer decide whether it was worth adding.

Do *not* simply add an index for every column.  Instead, learn how to write optimal indexes, then craft indexes based on queries - primarily `SELECTs`, but also `UPDATEs` and `DELETEs`.

A basic cookbook:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql